# Select two rows from a Database table

Tags: c#, linq

I guess it's a pretty standard task but I still can't get used to LINQ. I need exactly two rows from a table in my database and now I'm using two separate LINQ queries :

```
        imageInfo = AppConfigService.All().Where(a =>(a.ConfigProperty == "MaterialImages")).FirstOrDefault();
        imageLocation = AppConfigService.All().Where(c => (c.ConfigProperty == "DefaultImagePath")).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I want is to hold information in one variable, something like `imageInfo[0]` for my `MaterialImages` and `imageInfo[1]` for my `DefaultImagePath` or something like this. Even though I have very poor knowledge about LINQ I think the two queries are not needed.

Comment: Be careful of the `All` call: if that's a database call underneath and not a `IQueryable` object, you'll get all the rows, then filter in memory, which is probaly not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Concat` and `Take(1)`:

```
var imageInfoLocation =
    (from a in AppConfigService
     where a.ConfigProperty == "MaterialImages"
     select cust).Take(1)
    .Concat(
    (from a in AppConfigService
     where a.ConfigProperty == "DefaultImagePath"
     select cust).Take(1))
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'm gonna use yours so I'll accept it.

Comment: thanks, I've noticed but still it's easier to understand your code even though I like `dasblinkenlight` answer either.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single query below, but your original query is more readable:

```
var res = AppConfigService
    .All()
    .Where(a =>(a.ConfigProperty == "MaterialImages" || a.ConfigProperty == "DefaultImagePath"))
    .GroupBy(a => a.ConfigProperty)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

This will bring back a dictionary of no more than two items: one for the `ConfigProperty`, and one for the first or default item with that property. If there are no source rows with `"MaterialImages"` or `"DefaultImagePath"`, the result would contain fewer than two items. You can get the value from the dictionary by looking up using the corresponding constant as the key.

Answer (score 1):

i think its not possible to do in one query as you want first element form the list which satisfy two different condition , you can make use of union if you want to get result in one collection

```
var union = imageInfo = AppConfigService.All().
   Where(a =>(a.ConfigProperty == "MaterialImages")).FirstOrDefault().
  Union(
           AppConfigService.All().Where(c => (c.ConfigProperty ==
                                        "DefaultImagePath")).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following,

```
 var rows = AppConfigService.All().Where(a =>(a.ConfigProperty == "MaterialImages" || c.ConfigProperty == "DefaultImagePath"));
```

Comment: This is not correct. You didn´t define `c` and even then it would make no sense.

Comment: guys is obvious.. thats a typo, please consider.